# Send Alamofire JSON Array Swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I need to send request with this body:

```
[{"uid":777}]
```

How can i do it with Alamofire & SwiftyJSON

Answer (score -1):

Found on Alamofire's [own GitHub readme](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#post-request-with-json-encoded-parameters) :

```
let parameters = [
    "foo": [1,2,3],
    "bar": [
        "baz": "qux"
    ]
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://httpbin.org/post", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
// HTTP body: {"foo": [1, 2, 3], "bar": {"baz": "qux"}}
```

So I guess you'd write the data to send as follows :

```
let dataToSend = ["uid":"777"] // or more brackets if you want an Array of Dictionaries
```